# How do I cleanup data after Firebase .unAuth()?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase in a website (and it's awesome).

Via several `.on('child_added')` and `.on('value')` callbacks I'm populating a local store that is bound to my UI.

When a user signs out, I want to clean their data out of my local store. What is the recommended way to react to a user signing out with Firebase? Ideally I would like to pass a callback to `.unauth()` to do a cleanup. But there's no such callback.

My current solution is a bit messy...

- I listen with `onAuth()`.
- When `onAuth` triggered with a non-null value I set a variable `isLoggedIn = true`
- When `onAuth` is triggered with `null` and `isLoggedId === true` then I perform a cleanup.

I don't want to do a clean up *every* time `onAuth` is called with `null` because it does this on page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user triggers the logout, that means your code is calling [`unauth()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/unauth.html). That would also be the moment to clean up:

```
ref.unauth();
cleanupData();
```

But if the user gets signed out for another reason (i.e. their session expiring), then cleaning up in the `null` part of [`onAuth()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/onauth.html) makes sense. If you're worried about the initial `null`, you could wrap this in a check:

```
var previousAuthData = null;
ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    ...
  }
  else if (previousAuthData != null) {
    cleanupData();
  }
  previousAuthData = authData;
}
```